# change default email client for xubuntu 18.04

Tags: email-client

My "Settings/Preferred Application" is set to Evolution, yet when there is an email link in a web page Thunderbird is activated. I did some Internet research but could not find solution. I do not have 'Activities/Details' menu or similar. This is xubuntu 18.04 with Firefox as web browser and Evolution as email client. I abandoned Thunderbird because Lightning started to loose home calendar and I had to remove and re-install Lightning. Fortunately, my calendar entries were still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the preference in Firefox.  type `about:preferences` in the address bar and scroll down.  Then type `mail` in the box.

[image]

I don't have Evolution installed so I can't show exactly how to do it, but when you click on `Use Thunderbird Mail (default)` you will get a dropdown menu with other choices. Hopefully Evolution will be one of the choices.

Comment: Thx - Evolution is indeed a choice in dropdown menu. I also noticed that in Thunderbird Preferences, System Integration the use as default check mark was checked, but grayed out, could not uncheck it. Now it is unchecked.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!