# How do I set the default email client in LXQt?

Tags: lubuntu, email, alternative, lxqt

I could not find the default email client setting here:
Preferences >LXQt Settings > Session Settings > Default Applications.
Only choices for Terminal Emulation and Web Browser are there.
The default email client is Trojita and I want MailTo: to take me to Claws Mail.

Besides the Default Applications app, defaults can also be set in the Alternatives Configurator (G Alternatives).  No generic label is shown for an email client.  I believe it would be called, "x-email-client"  According to http://lxlinux.com/alternatives.html,

> An exec with the generic name is generally put in /usr/bin, for
> example, /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator. Also, each installed generic
> app should have a text file in /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/, which will
> list the alternatives for that app. The actual script linking the
> generic app to the real apps (alternatives) is contained in a file in
> /etc/alternatives/. So look in either of these directories to see the
> names of the generic programs already installed and look in the first
> one to find out the alternatives in each.

Comment: I haven't made the move beyond 18.04 quite yet. Does `sudo update-alternatives --config mail-client` do anything for you?

Comment: I don't think it'll work, anyway the Lubuntu manual covers it via https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.17/alternative_configurator.html  (sorry I don't know how it's changed, a quick look and I failed to find it, don't currently have time to look further sorry).

Comment: @KGIII That gave: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mail-client

Comment: Mailto: will mainly appear in a web browser in email address links. The web browser will have a setting for which app to use.  If Mailto: appears in a pdf or other document, then a default mail client designation might be useful.

Comment: I haven't had the time to properly look at this, still haven't... but it maybe via `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list` (which is from the package `lubuntu-default-settings`).   How it can be done nicely via GUI sorry I can't say, but that maybe where you can force the change...  Note: you didn't provide release details; so I'm basing this on my *hirsute* system  FYI:  linked page related to `lxsession` or LXDE isn't very helpful; LXQt is a different DE, so whilst `openbox` details are mostly the same.. many DE bits have changed; LXQt = RazorQt + ex-LXDE devs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Solution

### `xdg-settings`

The solution is defining which program to call for a given URL scheme with `xdg-settings` from the `xdg-utils` package:

```bsh
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler mailto claws-mail.desktop`
```

You can also use this to work with any URL scheme possible. Just make sure that for whatever program you want to use, it has a Desktop Entry file, as suggested by the final argument (since it's `claws-mail.desktop` and not `claws-mail`).

### MIME types

Another similar but unrelated thing is media types, or MIME types. These are not about URL schemes like `mailto:` but about the type of content or format a particular file has.

For example, a JPEG image would be `image/jpeg`. With various tools that manipulate MIME type associations, you could change which program opens such a file.

Despite this difference between MIME types and URL schemes, the XDG Specification does allow for a special [`x-scheme-handler`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html#idm45992893970944) MIME type. It appears this was added after [GNOME started using them](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/commit/a0b7bdc354f32290fbe9a8a9714e457d19eafcbd).

Technically, this is what the above command makes use of, altering your `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` file to add the following:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/mailto=claws-mail.desktop
```

Note there's a global configuration at `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list`, but the local one overrides it.

## one other thing

Firefox defines its own URL handlers, so it may be necessary to also make a change there if that is a browser you use, as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213462/237241).

---

## Not The Solution

### alternatives system

Using the alternatives system, whether by GUI or `update-alternatives` won't do what you want, as its purpose is to redefine general symbolic links. For example, there's a `x-www-browser` that could theoretically be defined to any number of browsers.

If there was something like `x-email-client`, you could theoretically use the above solution to set the default handler to it and *then* you could swap email clients out through the alternatives system. Unfortunately, there isn't an `x-email-client` or anything like it, just the likes of `mailx` for use on the command line.

### LXQt default applications

You know this already, but this doesn't work. The reason for the small list is that these only change the values of environment variables, of which only a small handful are supported at all.

Sadly, these are not particularly reliable ways of even setting the default browser, as evidenced by [this task](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T53) Lubuntu is tracking.

### GUI

At time of writing, I can't find a general GUI front end to accomplish this particular task. There are some that work with MIME types, but not the URL scheme handlers.

Some desktop environments may implement some sort of GUI for this within the context of their desktop environment. KDE does this and you can see it in Kubuntu, but it's hard to pull that particular feature outside of the context of the KDE environment.

LXQt does have `lxqt-config-file-associations` but it has several [issues](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1004), including that you cannot add or remove new entries and `x-scheme-handler` types are not supported, although the [fix for that](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-config/commit/eff9efd51964c6928bc2154442ad3fb5bdb94737) latter issue appears to be in 0.16.0 which should find its way in Hirsute Hippo.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with another browser setting itself as the default and not allowing me to set Firefox as the default.  I found the needed setting under **Preferences > LXQt Settings > File Associations > Default Applications**.

You can set the default email client and default file manager there as well.